# BTC-E - Is there an official limit on frequency of requests that can be made?

Tags: api, btce

Does anyone know if there is an official limit on the number of requests that can be made to btc-e.com? I know bitstamp will ban your ip address if it detects more than 600 requests per 10 minutes. I checked the terms, FAQ, and knowledge base and searched briefly on google but did not find much.

Anybody with any experience on what is the highest acceptable frequency of requests that can be made?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I log the price in every five seconds for more than a month now and no ban happened.

Answer (score 1):

At around 50 to 60 requests/second their host provider (I believe cloudlfare) starts to error.